# Getting NullPointerException when trying to access Selenium Webdriver instance in below scenario.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to create a framework where I can run my test cases(test tags in xml file) in parallel in different browsers. I have tried using all combinations of testNG annotations but after reading a blog came to know that this can only be achieved by using testNg listners. I am using ThreadLocal to keep my driver thread-safe. I am getting null pointer exception when trying to access Webdriver in my test cases class in line LocalDriverManager.getDriver().get(url);

This is LocalBrowserFactory.Class

```
package BrowserFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import DataProvider.ConfigDataProvider;

public class LocalDriverFactory {

        public static WebDriver createInstance(String browserName) {
            WebDriver driver = null;
            ConfigDataProvider config=new ConfigDataProvider();

            if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", config.getgeckoPath());
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            }
            if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("internet")) {
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            }
            if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", config.getchromePath());
                driver = new ChromeDriver();

            }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            return driver;
        }

}
```

This is my LocalDriverManager.class

```
package BrowserFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LocalDriverManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }

    public static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

This is my ConfigPropertyReader.class

```
package DataProvider;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigDataProvider {

    static Properties p;
    public ConfigDataProvider()
    {   

        File f =new File("C:/Eclipse/parallelframework/configuration/config.properties");

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            p=new Properties();
            p.load(fis);

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println("Custom Exception- cannot load properties file"+e.getMessage());
        }       
    }

    public String getvalue(String key)  
    {
        return p.getProperty(key);
    }

    public  String getUrl()
    {
        return p.getProperty("url");    
    }   

    public String getchromePath()
    {
        return p.getProperty("chromepath");
    }

    public String getgeckoPath()
    {
        return p.getProperty("firefoxpath");
    }

    public String getIEPath()
    {
        return System.getProperty("User.dir")+p.getProperty("IEPath");
    }

}
```

This is WebDriverListner.class

```
package Listners;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import BrowserFactory.LocalDriverFactory;
import BrowserFactory.LocalDriverManager;

public class WebDriverListner implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
            System.out.println(browserName);
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
            LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
            System.out.println("Driver Set");
        }

    }

    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my sample testcase.class

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import BrowserFactory.LocalDriverManager;

public class sampleTest {


    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.ndtv.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.facebook.com");

    }

    private void invokeBrowser(String url) {

    LocalDriverManager.getDriver().get(url);

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems that the afterInvocation and beforeInvocation methods need to have their names switched...

Comment: In this line LocalDriverManager.getDriver().get(url); there is getDriver which returns webDriver.get() as per your code, so it becomes LocalDriverManager.webDriver.get().get(url) which is confusing to me. I think issue is here. Or you need to put this part of code WebDriver driver = null; outside of class LocalDriverFactory

Answer (score 1):

Your Listener code is messed up. You basically have the `beforeInvocation` and `afterInvocation` in the wrong order.

Here's how it should have looked like

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class WebDriverListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
            LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You basically would setup the webdriver into the thread local variable (push the webdriver instance into the thread local variable's context) from within the `beforeInvocation` and then within your `afterInvocation` method, you would pop it out and clean up the webdriver instance (by calling `quit()` ). In your case, your code is doing the opposite.

For more details you can refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/).